# How to update a value in python dictionary if the key appears multiple times without importing?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, methods, key

Say that I have a list of tuples with multiple occurrences of the same key. I want to convert them into a dictionary but I don't want the keys to repeat or overwrite previous keys. I want to do it without importing packages.

```
[("John", 14), ("Bob", 5), ("John", 21)]

turn it into:

{"John": [14, 21],
"Bob": [5]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
yourlist = [("John", 14), ("Bob", 5), ("John", 21)]
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in yourlist:
    d[k].append(v)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'John': [14, 21], 'Bob': [5]})
```

To make it an actual `dict`ionary, add this line:

```
d = dict(d)
```

Then:

```
print(d)
```

Would give:

```
{'John': [14, 21], 'Bob': [5]}
```

**Edit:**

As OP mentioned in the comments, he doesn't want to use any imports. So try:

```
yourlist = [("John", 14), ("Bob", 5), ("John", 21)]
d = {}
for x, y in yourlist:
    if x in d:
        d[x].append(y)
    else:
        d[x] = [y]
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'John': [14, 21], 'Bob': [5]}
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add that I do not want to import packages. I updated the question

Comment: @anonymousdude123 Check my **Edit:** part. I don't use any additional modules.

Comment: @anonymousdude123 Remember to upvote and accept if it's useful :)

Answer (score 1):

as `nike` would say... just do it:

```
my_dict = {}
for item in list_of_tuples:
    if item[0] not in my_dict.keys():
        my_dict[item[0]] = [item[1]]
    else:
        my_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])
```

this will make sure any keys that aren't in the dict get a list value assigned to them

you need the membership check because you will be adding values via `.append()` which is a method that `NoneType` does not have and so will throw an error if you attempt to create the key/value pair directly

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple (if not optimal) comprehension:

```
>>> data = [("John", 14), ("Bob", 5), ("John", 21)]
>>> {name: [v for k, v in data if k == name] for name, _ in data}
{'John': [14, 21], 'Bob': [5]}
```